# Convert a MongoCursor from ->find() to an array

Tags: php, mongodb

```
$jokes = $collection->find();
```

How do I convert `$jokes` into an array?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use PHP's [`iterator_to_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php) function, as suggested in example 1 of the [`MongoCursor` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursor.php):

```
$jokes = $collection->find();
$jokesArray = iterator_to_array($jokes);
```

Comment: Is is a best practice to get result as array for mongodb?

Comment: This was very handy as some operations you can't do on a cursor, just convert to json

Comment: Thanks @Chris Henry

Answer (score 10):

**iterator_to_array** is not working for nesting more than 2 levels,

Using **typeMap** you can convert root and its document to array, It will work for any level of nesting

**findOne($filter,$options)**

```
$options = ["typeMap" => ['root' => 'array', 'document' => 'array']];
$collection->findOne(['myId' => $id ], $options); // returns array
```

**find($filter,$options)**

```
$options = ["typeMap" => ['root' => 'array', 'document' => 'array']];
$collection->find(['myId' => $id ], $options)->toArray();
```

Comment: Hello @satya-prakash-patel -- is there a way to set this globally, for all find & findOne operations, so that it doesn't have to be supplied as an option on every single query? Thanks.

Comment: nevermind, that comment, it looks like you can pass the typemap as an option on your connector, too. e.g.: $conn = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017", [], $options);

Answer (score 9):

As a side note to Chris's answer:

> array iterator_to_array ( Traversable $iterator [, bool $use_keys =
>   true ] )

Pay attention to the optional second parameter, if it's set to true (default), the final array will be indexed using the "_id" field from each document.

If you applied a sort in the mongo query, the final array might not be what you expected, meaning that the sort order will not be preserved (unless you set the **$use_keys** parameter to **false**)

Comment: NOTE: This also removes the associative array keys and changes them to numeric.

Answer (score 3):

`iterator_to_array()` forces the driver to load all of the results into memory, **so do not do this for result sets that are larger than memory!**
use this

```
$jokes = $collection->find();
foreach ($jokes as $joke) {
    var_dump($joke);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

a lot easier:

```
findeOne()->getArrayCopy();
```

as mentioned before: beware from loading large resultsets and convert them to an array

you can also set your preferences with the typeMap option

```
'typeMap' =>[
      'document' => 'array',
       'root' => 'array'
                ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got issue with the multidimentional result.
to convert the multidimentional result to array you can use below function.

```
public function convertMongoResultToArray($result)
{
    if (is_object($result)) {
        if ($result instanceof \MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument) {
            $result = $result->getArrayCopy();
        } elseif ($result instanceof \MongoDB\Model\BSONArray) {
            $result = iterator_to_array($result);
        } elseif ($result instanceof \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId) {
            $result = (string) $result;
        }

        if (is_array($result)) {
            foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
                $result[$key] = $this->convertMongoResultToArray($value);
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

for above function you can pass the result of the mongo query.

in the function we will covert possible three different types of object to array.

1. \MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument
2. \MongoDB\Model\BSONArray
3. \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId

we will loop through the every key of the result and call function recursively if the key consist array.

final result will provide php array.

Answer (score -1):

find() basically returns MongoDB cursor  http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php

this should work for your case

```
$cursor = $collection->find();
foreach($cursor as $jokes) {
 print_r($jokes);
}
```

Comment: @xe4me the fact that it *doesn't answer the question* seems like a bit of a flaw.

Answer (score -1):

in case if someone came to here, you can also use [`toArray`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-cursor.toarray.php) method.

> (mongodb >=1.0.0)
>
> MongoDB\Driver\Cursor::toArray — Returns an array containing all
>   results for this cursor

```
$jokes = $collection->find()->toArray();
```

or :

```
$jokes = $collection->find();
$jokesArray = $jokes->toArray();
```