# Convert PHP mongodb findOne result to old associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I'm having issues with the new mongodb driver for php.
While iterator_to_array works ok for ->find, if I only return one document it has MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument format.

```
$result = $db->clients->findOne(array('_id' => $id));
$result = (array) $result;
```

In Mongo the document looks something like:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("3894713i4b13iu412"), 
    "active" : true, 
    "logo" : "this is logo", 
    "settings" : {
        "email" : "days", 
        "testMode" : false
    }, 
    "stats" : {
        "f" : {
            "all" : [
                {
                    "count" : NumberLong(15846), 
                    "sum" : NumberLong(149479)
                }, 
                {
                    "count" : NumberLong(15846), 
                    "sum" : NumberLong(148891)
                }, 
                {
                    "count" : NumberLong(15846), 
                    "sum" : {
                        "1" : NumberLong(15522), 
                        "2" : NumberLong(324)
                    }
                }
            ]
        }, 
        "l" : {
            "order" : ISODate("2016-12-05T09:10:53.855+0000"), 
            "feedback" : ISODate("2016-12-05T08:34:48.403+0000")
        }
    }, 
    "title" : "hhh.ro", 
    "url" : "sdfasdf"
}
```

This will only turn first level elements into an array, but nested document elements still remain MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument;

iterator_to_array doesn't work because this is not something iterable.

How do I convert entire document to an associative array like the old mongo driver or a stdClass?

Comment: May be you can try this json_decode(json_encode($result), true);

Comment: It makes _id like this  ["$oid"]=> string(24) "5784d428f079959a088b4595"

Comment: You tried this $db->clients->findOne(array('_id' => $id))->toArray()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670036/convert-a-mongocursor-from-find-to-an-array

Comment: that's for find. findOne doesn't return an iterator. And yes, I tried toArray.

Answer (score 4):

you can set how the data is returned globally in `database->setCollection` options, Set typeMap to array

```
'typeMap' =>[
    'document' => 'array',
    'root' => 'array'
]
```

[Link to Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.persistence.deserialization.php#mongodb.persistence.typemaps)

Comment: typeMap is not supported in findOne options array  http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.findone.php

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find the setCollection suggested by @Delcon in PHP MongoDB library so I used the below method.

typeMap option can also be set in the options array inside findOne.

```
$someCollection->findOne(
[],
['typeMap' => ['root' => 'array', 'document' => 'array', 'array' => 'array']]
);
```

[Link to Doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.3/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-findOne/)

edit:

You could also pass the options array to the connector to set it globally as described by this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950597/9160306) post.

```
$options = ["typeMap" => ['root' => 'array', 'document' => 'array']];
$conn = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017", [], $options);
```